# derive path from adjacency matrix with numpy operations

Tags: python, numpy, graph-theory

I need to derive a path from an adjacency matrix in a fast way (I have 40000 points).

If a is the adjacency matrix:

```
a = array([[0., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
           [0., 0., 1., 1., 0.],
           [1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
           [1., 0., 0., 1., 0.]])
```

then I want to get:

```
path(a) = [0, 2, 1, 3, 4]
```

For now, I am using a while loop to get the path, but it is slow:

```
def create_path_from_joins(joins):
    # not assuming the path is connected
    i = 0
    path = [i]
    elems = np.where(joins[i] == 1)
    elems = elems[0].tolist()
    join_to = set(elems) - set(path)

    while len(join_to) > 0:
        # choose the one that is not already in the path
        elem = list(join_to)[0]
        path.append(elem)
        i = elem
        elems = np.where(np.array(joins[i]) == 1)
        elems = elems[0].tolist()
        join_to = set(elems) - set(path)
    return path
```

So I wanted to know if this can be done with matrix operations somehow in order to make it faster.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you summarize the logic of the output?

Comment: @mozway, I'm trying to construct the path in the adjacency matrix. For instance, 1 in coordinates (0,2), means that 0 is joined to 2. Then in row 2, 1 in (2,1) means 2 goes to 1. So far the path is 0,2,1 ... and so on.

Comment: Yes, I got that (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75362720/16343464)), but how do you decide on which node is the first? And is your graph directed?

Comment: Which node is the 1st doesn't matter (could be 0). Then, the logic in the comment. Finally returns to the original node but that can be added by hand. Is for the tsp problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might remove the visited destinations from the adjacency matrix. It depends however which constraints you give on how building the path.

```
A = np.array([[0., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
              [0., 0., 1., 1., 0.],
              [1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
              [1., 0., 0., 1., 0.]], dtype=int)   # int,  so later we can test wether A==0

B = A.copy()                        # auxiliary matrix to work with
mx, my = B.shape
#istart = np.random.randint(mx)     # chose a random starting point
istart = 0                          # OR chose zero to start with
print("starting point is", istart)

path = []
path.append(istart)

ended = False
while not ended:
    inew = (B[istart]!=0).argmax(axis=0)  # find the next point as first element in the row that is not zero
    B[istart, inew] = 0
    B[inew, istart] = 0                   # remove this path element since it has been visited now
    ended = np.all(B==0)                  # check wether B == 0
    if ended: break
    path.append(inew)                     # insert the visited point into the path list
    istart = inew                         # prepare next step

print('path', path)
```

Comment: I also thought about "deleting the symmetry" while going through the matrix. The problem here is the copy. Would that be faster even considering the copy?  Please consider the magnitude of the dimensions I added to the problem.

Comment: (a) do you need A after the path computation? If not, then you can remove B and use just A. (B) it seems from your example that the path-array has always size n (with A having size n*n). If that is true you can gain speed with (1) turn `path` in a numpy array, remove `apend`, adress `path[j]` (2) turn the while-loop in a for-loop, (3) remove everything with  `ended`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the path between 0 and the last node pointing back to 0, you can use [`networkx`](https://networkx.org).

```
a = np.array([[0., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
              [0., 0., 1., 1., 0.],
              [1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
              [1., 0., 0., 1., 0.]])

import networkx as nx

# convert adjacency matrix to graph
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(a)
# or
#G = nx.from_edgelist(zip(*np.nonzero(a)))

# get last node pointing back to 0
last_node = np.nonzero(a[0])[0][-1]  # last_node = 4
# add greater weight to the edge between the last node and 0
G[0][last_node]['weight'] = 2

# get minimum spanning tree
T = nx.minimum_spanning_tree(G)

# get path between 0 and last node
path = next(nx.all_simple_paths(T, source=0, target=last_edge))
```

Output:

```
[0, 2, 1, 3, 4]
```

Graph before and after conversion to minimum spanning tree:

[image]
[image]

##### alternative with random start/end (here first 1)

```
import networkx as nx

# convert adjacency matrix to graph
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(a)

# get a random edge to define start/end
start, end = next(zip(*np.nonzero(a)))
# remove it
G.remove_edge(start, end)

# get path between start and end
path = next(nx.all_simple_paths(G, source=start, target=end))
```

Output: `[0, 4, 3, 1, 2]`

Comment: the last solution you posted but with  nx.from_edgelist(zip(*np.nonzero(a))) is taking longer than the original